# Excel OData Feed Organizational account "credential type isn't supported for this resource"

Tags: c#, excel, authentication, azure-active-directory, odata

[OData feed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQL0D.png)

I'm trying to use the excel OData feed using the Organizational account but I get the message "We were unable to connect because this credential type isn't supported for this resource. Please choose another credential type." Using fiddler I notice that it is using the response mode Form Post. What could be the issue?

Comment: The connection doesn't want a user name and password.  It is expecting default credentials using the user login account.

Comment: I'm using the default credentials (User Login account).

Comment: Are you connecting to a database on same machine or remote machine?  I'm not familar with the error message.  I doesn't seem like it is a standard error message so I'm suspecting it is one of your companies utilities that is generating the error.  This leads me to believe it is a Group Policy issue.  That the database group setup by your MIS isn't working from a remote machine.  This is only a guess.

Comment: I've added a picture under the link "OData feed message" so you can see from where the error is coming from

Comment: It looks like you are going through a custom interface similar to following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-odata.  You may be able to bypass the custom interface and connect directly to the source.   You would have to look at the source of the pop up to see how to bypass.